# Configurable reports plugin, sql query

Tags: sql, moodle, sql-query-store

I am using the configurable reports input, I need a sql Query to show in the report, the name and surname of the user, the date when he first entered the site, the list of courses next to the scorm that he completed and the completition status.

Comment: OK.And how can we help you to achieve this goal ?

Comment: [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.